# Booster badge I earned for an answer links to the wrong answer

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, badges

I recently earned the [Booster](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster) badge for an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46269795/4909087). Clicking on the Badge from my profile should've taken me directly to my answer there, instead it took me to a different answer on the page, written by another user. Both the link on my profile as well as well as the link from the [Booster badge list here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster?userid=4909087) cause the same erroneous behavior (redirect to another user's answer).

I do see that the link I've earned the badge for is a link that takes you to the same answer that I'm incorrectly being redirected to. This doesn't happen with any of the other answers on the list, since none of them link to other answers on the site.

TLDR; badge should link to the answer I earned the badge for, which it doesn't (at least, not for *this* specific answer from [this list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster?userid=4909087)).

Looks like a bug, devs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Clicking on the Badge from my profile should've taken me directly to my answer

No, why should that happen?

From the badge description:

> Share a link to a post later visited by 300 unique IP addresses.

and in your answer you start with:

> As this answer ..

and that links to:

`https://stackoverflow.com/a/46269860/4909087`

where 46269860 is the id of that other answer and 4909087 is your userid.

You are not boosting views on your answer, you're boosting views of that other answer and it looks like 300 people actually followed that link to check that answer out.

It seems logical that this happens as you have the accepted answer there.

For example [this answer that is not yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26265819/how-to-merge-a-series-and-dataframe/40762674#40762674) also earned you a Booster badge. No idea where you share that link. (Well, [revision 9](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26265819/revisions) might be the culprit there.)

Comment: I understand this, but the badge should link to the answer I earned the badge for, not the link I boosted... is my point. At least, that's how it is for the other links on my [Badge history](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/261/booster?userid=4909087), so the lack of consistency here confuses me.

Comment: @cs95  you seem to selectively check these links. See my update

Comment: Re: your edit, my word, that's interesting. It means the link doesn't have to sit in your answer (for reference, I boosted the link inside [an edit to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26265819/6)).

Comment: @cs95 no, it is not restricted to any post/comment on SE. Users can share the same link on Twitter or any social media and still get the badge.

Comment: Okay, so is this question nothing more than my misunderstanding of how the Booster badge logic is implemented? Seems like as long as your ID is associated with the link, they can trace it back to you when it is clicked. TIL!